# Could StackTrace be utilized when <compilation debug="true"> in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, stack-trace

I know I check it programmatically from

```
 ConfigurationSection configSection =
      (CompilationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection( "system.web/compilation" );
```

I know that it is also somewhat slower to have  in production ... yet if we are in a kind of beta it does not harm yet ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's available both in Debug and Release builds but it'll include more data (such as source line numbers) if you have the PDB in debug mode.